# How to scroll control into view in WPF application when onscreen keyboard opens?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-10

#### Problem

How to scroll the current (focused) control into view when using a WPF application on Windows10 in fullscreen mode and opening the keyboard (TabTip)?

#### What I have:

- Windows 10 V10.0.16299.192 64Bit
- .net 4.6.1
- classic WPF application maximized without window style (and topmost)
- Tablet mode/Desktop mode

#### What I tried so far:

1. Getting window handle from TabTip and get information about window visiblity and window height to adjust my WPF window height to move alle content to view when the keyboard is visible.
   This worked in 10.0.14393 until windows updated.
2. Using [WPFTabTip](https://github.com/maximcus/WPFTabTip) to automate the keyboard which results in wild flickering of the keyboard when tapping into a control but not scrolling the control into view

#### Questions

- What am I missing in terms of WPF controls like scrollviewers around other controls to enable the scrolling when the keyboard shows up?
- Is the current windows behaviour of not scrolling the control into view just a bug which will be fixed in a future windows update?
- Do I need to update to 4.6.2 and hope the scrolling works in the new version?

Comment: A window does not scroll by default.  If you want the content to be scrollable, you need to wrap it in a `ScrollViewer`.  This is not a bug; it is by design.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with the same problem and here is my solution:

**VirtualKeyboardHelper.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adjust parent control when child control got focus and virtual keyboard shown
    /// </summary>
    public class VirtualKeyboardHelper
    {
        bool _isParentAdjusted = false;

        const int DefaultShiftSize = 300;
        public int ShiftSize { get; set; } = DefaultShiftSize;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String sClassName, String sAppName);

        static bool IsVirtualKeyboardShown()
        {
            var iHandle = (int)FindWindow("IPTIP_Main_Window", "");
            return (iHandle > 0);
        }

        private void DoSetAdjustmentOnFocus(UserControl owner, UIElement child)
        {            
            child.GotFocus += delegate
            {
                var m = owner.Margin;
                if (IsVirtualKeyboardShown())
                {
                    owner.Margin = new Thickness(m.Left, m.Top - ShiftSize, m.Right, m.Bottom);
                    _isParentAdjusted = true;
                }
            };

            child.LostFocus += delegate
            {
                var m = owner.Margin;
                if (_isParentAdjusted)
                    owner.Margin = new Thickness(m.Left, m.Top + ShiftSize, m.Right, m.Bottom);
            };
        }

        public static void SetAdjustmentOnFocus(UserControl owner, UIElement child, int shiftSize = DefaultShiftSize) 
            => new VirtualKeyboardHelper() { ShiftSize = shiftSize }.DoSetAdjustmentOnFocus(owner, child);

        public static void SetAdjustmentOnFocus(UserControl owner, List<UIElement> children)
        {
            foreach (var c in children)
                SetAdjustmentOnFocus(owner, c);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyControl.cs**

```
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {        
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // _textCity - is a TextBox defined in XAML
            VirtualKeyboardHelper.SetAdjustmentOnFocus(this, _textCity, 400);
            VirtualKeyboardHelper.SetAdjustmentOnFocus(this, _textState);
        }
    }
```

This solution could be improved by implementing attched property to use it in XAML.